# Displaying an image with an absolute path on server

Tags: django

Suppose I have an image on the server machine (Django on Windows) at `C:/myimage.jpg`. I want to display this image on the client machine. The image path is passed to a template as a context variable `image_path`. It is important that the path is absolute and not relative. Here is my attempt on the template:

```
<img src="{{ image_path }}" />
```

However, the client does not see an image at all. My first guess is that when it reads `image_path`, it actually reads `C:/myimage.jpg`, and therefore looks on the client machine, rather than the server. How can I make it look for the image on the server instead?

Answer (score 1):

Using absolute paths for static content within the app is not a correct idea. You should use images using the following method,

add this in your `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and then accessing the image using

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

please read the [guidelines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could tell a browser to look in a specific file location on the server, how could that ever be a good idea? What if the user entered the path to the settings.py file containing your database credentials?

Clearly, you can only look for files via URLs, and those URLs actually have to be mapped to actual files by the server. So you need to configure your web server in such a way that it maps a URL to the place your files are, and then you can use that URL in your template.